# Any way to disable word deselecting text after applying the highlighter tool?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pretty much as the title says.

Still, a bit more explanation to avoid misunderstandings:

If I select some text, apply a font colour change, the text remains selected.
If I, however, apply the 'text highlighter' tool (i.e. the - by default - yellow highlighter) the text is now unselected.  To be able to change or remove the highlighted colour, you have to select the piece of text again.

I'd like the text to remain selected after using the highlighter tool as well and get rid of this inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: You could write a short macro that will highlight the selected text, and assign a shortcut key to make it quicker to use.  The text will still be selected after the macro has applied the highlighting.

Comment: @Tanya that sounds like a proper workaround - do you want to detail it out a bit in a proper response below?  I've never written macros and I don't even know where to start, let alone what to write!

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Developer tab in the ribbon first (File | Options | Customize Ribbon).

Then select some text (it doesn't matter what it is) - but DON'T highlight it.

To create this simple macro, you can just use the Record Macro button (which will record every keystroke/button click in Word until you click the Stop Recording button).

When you click Record Macro button, the Record Macro dialog will appear - you can give it a meaningful name (rather than Macro1).

By default it will save your macro in the Normal template (so it is later accessible by all documents) (you may prefer to create a custom Word template to save your macros to and save that it in your Startup folder instead, to keep them separate from Normal template in the unlikely event Normal corrupts).

You'll also see the Keyboard button, click this to go to separate dialog to assign a keyboard shortcut to your macro.

Once you click OK button on the Record Macro dialog, the macro is recording your actions.

Just click the highlighter to apply your yellow highlighting.  Then press the Stop Recording button (because you only want to record the action of highlighting the existing text selection).

To view the actual macro code, you can access it via the Visual Basic button at far left of the Developer tab.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior for the Text Highlighter feature in Word. The text will not keep selected after you applied Text Highlighter color.

To remove the Highlighted color, please do:

1. Select the text that you want to remove highlighting from, or press Ctrl+A to select all of the text in the document.
2. On the **Home** tab,click the arrow next to **Text Highlight Color**.
3. Click **No Color**.

To change the highlight color, we can also do:

1. On the **Home** tab, click the arrow next to **Text Highlight Color**.
2. Click the color that you want. The **Text Highlight Color** button displays the selected color, and the mouse pointer becomes a [image]when you point to the area of your document that contains text.
3. Select the text or graphic that you want to highlight.
4. To stop highlighting, click the arrow next to **Text Highlight Color**[image] and click **Stop Highlighting**, or press Esc.

Comment: You seriously think I can't remove highlighting?  What on earth gave you that impression?!?  Your post is off topic, sorry.